# Why is Arcgis putting my address out in the sea?

Tags: python, arcgis

I am following the tutorial here: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/using-the-geocode-function/

I am simply trying to get the longitude and latitude of a shop.

```
from arcgis.geocoding import geocode
from arcgis import GIS
gis = GIS()

single_line_address = "20 Sexton St, Limerick, Ireland"
geocode(single_line_address)[0]['location']
```

This puts my location in the Seychelles, but I should be in Ireland.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would assume that the module misinterprets your address. Try simplifying the address and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I have made it even simpler by removing the street info, and keeping the county. I am still out in the middle of the sea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output:

```
{'x': -8.621920984527977, 'y': 52.6602769888287}
```

X is the longitude and y is the latitude. So the coordinates are correct, just swap them: https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=52.6602769888287,-8.621920984527977